# How to export folder located at some path and use its files in other folder

Tags: python, import

I have a folder present at the path `/home/krishma/test`. test folder contains a subfolders and python files.

```
example:
test -> db -> db.py
```

I want to use python files of test folder in second folder which is present at `/user/scripts`.

```
example:
scripts -> test -> test.py
```

In second folder,
I have a file named `test.py` and I want to import `db.py` present in 1st test folder.

How can I import `db.py` in `test.py`?

Answer (score 0):

You could read your current directory and manipulate the path as required.

```
import os
current_folder= os.getcwd()
```

for path manipulation have a look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches to this problem,

1. Convert your db directory to package by adding **init**.py file to it.

To create package have a look at this-https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/python/python-package

2. By modifying the sys.path.

When importing a file, Python only searches the directory that the entry-point script is running from and sys.path which includes locations such as the package installation directory (it's actually a little more complex than this, but this covers most cases).

However, you can add to the Python path at runtime:

```
# some_file.py
import sys
# insert at 1, 0 is the script path (or '' in REPL)
sys.path.insert(1, '/path/to/application/app/folder')

import file
```

Have look at this-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder